# SELECT isn't storing data in PL/SQL variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

Okay so once again I did a script in which I need to store some data into PL/SQL variables. Now for some reason I can't store said data. I tried the query by itself without INTO statement to prove if the query was wrong by any means and I get the result I expected. But once I get to the anonymous block with INTO isn't working and the output says that there was no data found.

Here is the script.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
VAR TP1 VARCHAR2(30);
EXEC TP1 := &TIPO_PROPIEDAD_1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:TP1);
DECLARE
    V_CANT_1 PROPIEDAD.NRO_PROPIEDAD%TYPE;
    V_TOTAL_1 PROPIEDAD.VALOR_ARRIENDO%TYPE;
    V_DESC_1 TIPO_PROPIEDAD.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD%TYPE;
BEGIN
-- CONSULTA 1
    SELECT
        COUNT(PR.NRO_PROPIEDAD),
        SUM(PR.VALOR_ARRIENDO),
        TP.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD
        INTO
            V_CANT_1,
            V_TOTAL_1,
            V_DESC_1
    FROM
        PROPIEDAD PR INNER JOIN TIPO_PROPIEDAD TP
        ON PR.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD = TP.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD
    WHERE
        TP.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD = :TP1
    GROUP BY
        TP.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD;
   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('RESUMEN DE : ' || V_DESC_1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL DE PROPIEDADES : ' || V_CANT_1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALOR TOTAL ARRIENDO : ' || V_TOTAL_1);
END;
```

Here I'll put the data types of both PROPIEDAD and TIPO_PROPIEDAD in case someone wants to help me with this.

PROPIEDAD:

```
Nombre                  ¿Nulo?   Tipo         
----------------------- -------- ------------ 
NRO_PROPIEDAD           NOT NULL NUMBER(6)       
VALOR_ARRIENDO          NOT NULL NUMBER(7)       
ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
```

TIPO_PROPIEDAD:

```
Nombre              ¿Nulo?   Tipo         
------------------- -------- ------------ 
ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)  
DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
```

And also, I'll put the error in here.

```
Informe de error -
ORA-01403: No se ha encontrado ningún dato
ORA-06512: en línea 7
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

Also, when I run the query without bind variables as a normal query it does finds data:

```
    SELECT
        COUNT(PR.NRO_PROPIEDAD),
        SUM(PR.VALOR_ARRIENDO),
        TP.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD
    FROM
        PROPIEDAD PR INNER JOIN TIPO_PROPIEDAD TP
        ON PR.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD = TP.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD
    WHERE
        TP.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD = 'A'
    GROUP BY
        TP.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD;
```

Result:

```
COUNT(PR.NRO_PROPIEDAD) SUM(PR.VALOR_ARRIENDO) TP.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD
7                       3445000                Casa sin Amoblar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've posted, you've missed or ignored an earlier error your script will produce; this:

```
EXEC TP1 := &TIPO_PROPIEDAD_1;
```

should be

```
EXEC :TP1 := '&TIPO_PROPIEDAD_1';
```

Without the colon your reference to `TP1` will be treated as a local variable rather than the bind variable you declared, and you will see "PLS-00201: identifier 'TP1' must be declared" (after it prompts you for the bind value, which might have made you assume that part was working). That means the actual bind variable is still null when you use it your `where` clause later, so there are no matches.

And without the single quotes it will treat the substitution value `A` as another identifier rather than a string, and again the bind variable will still be null.

Your `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:TP1);` debug will also error with "Unknown command" as you are calling that outside a PL/SQL block; you can do `PRINT TP1` (with or without a colon!) instead.

Comment: This. During this whole morning. It was just this. I knew that the data was there because I executed it before through a normal query (WHERE TP.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD = 'A') and never thought about this one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because there are no matching rows so the (self-explanatory) exception `NO_DATA_FOUND` is thrown.

If you want to output a single row then aggregate across the entire result-set:

```sql
DECLARE
    V_CANT_1 PROPIEDAD.NRO_PROPIEDAD%TYPE;
    V_TOTAL_1 PROPIEDAD.VALOR_ARRIENDO%TYPE;
    V_DESC_1 TIPO_PROPIEDAD.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD%TYPE;
BEGIN
-- CONSULTA 1
  SELECT COUNT(PR.NRO_PROPIEDAD),
         SUM(PR.VALOR_ARRIENDO),
         MAX(TP.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD)
  INTO   V_CANT_1,
         V_TOTAL_1,
         V_DESC_1
  FROM   PROPIEDAD PR INNER JOIN TIPO_PROPIEDAD TP
         ON PR.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD = TP.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD
  WHERE  TP.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD = :TP1;
   
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('RESUMEN DE : ' || V_DESC_1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL DE PROPIEDADES : ' || V_CANT_1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALOR TOTAL ARRIENDO : ' || V_TOTAL_1);
END;
/
```

Which will always return a single row and should output:

> ```
> RESUMEN DE : 0
> TOTAL DE PROPIEDADES : 
> VALOR TOTAL ARRIENDO :
> ```

Since there are no matching rows so the count will be `0` and there is nothing to `SUM` and no description.

---

Alternatively, you can handle the exception:

```sql
DECLARE
    V_CANT_1 PROPIEDAD.NRO_PROPIEDAD%TYPE;
    V_TOTAL_1 PROPIEDAD.VALOR_ARRIENDO%TYPE;
    V_DESC_1 TIPO_PROPIEDAD.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD%TYPE;
BEGIN
-- CONSULTA 1
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(PR.NRO_PROPIEDAD),
           SUM(PR.VALOR_ARRIENDO),
           TP.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD
    INTO   V_CANT_1,
           V_TOTAL_1,
           V_DESC_1
    FROM   PROPIEDAD PR INNER JOIN TIPO_PROPIEDAD TP
           ON PR.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD = TP.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD
    WHERE  TP.ID_TIPO_PROPIEDAD = :TP1
    GROUP BY
           TP.DESC_TIPO_PROPIEDAD;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      V_CANT_1 := 0;
      V_TOTAL_1 := NULL;
      V_DESC_1 := NULL;
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
      -- Do something to handle this as well.
      RAISE;
  END;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('RESUMEN DE : ' || V_DESC_1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL DE PROPIEDADES : ' || V_CANT_1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALOR TOTAL ARRIENDO : ' || V_TOTAL_1);
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GbdzASTO)

Comment: But why, there are matching rows, I executed the query without INTO and it's working perfectly fine. I don't get it.

Comment: @pr0vis0ri0_ You have not included any sample data or any details of the parameters that you are passing to the anonymous block. All we have to go on is the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception and that would not be raised if there was any matching data; therefore, we have to assume that the database knows what it is talking about and whatever filters you are using does not match any data. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75792158/edit) and provide a [MRE] is you want more detail.

Comment: Like that? I didn't get the whole MRE thing.

Comment: @pr0vis0ri0_ I have edited my answer with a link to a fiddle that shows it working when there is no data and then when there is data (and then when there is too much data). If that is not representative of your question then you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75792158/edit) and provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that do represent your data as well as details of what user input you put into the query.

Comment: Thanks for your help MT0, through your answer I've learned more about how to formulate a question in a rightful way. Alex Poole found out that it was because I missed apostrophes on the EXEC :TP1 ...